# Adding Minor Gridlines in Logarithmic Chart in Charts.Js v2.9.4

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I want to draw minor gridlines in the chart drawn by the following below to get the result similar to x-axis in following image (except instead of tick value shown in simple number instead of power i.e. instead 10^0 it should show 1 and instead of 10^1 it should show 10 and so on. Image is os meant to show just the gridlines on x-axis):

[image: Log Gridline Image]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- saved from url=(0014)about:internet -->
<html>
<head>
    <title>Chart</title>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=Edge'>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-colorschemes"></script>
    <style>
        body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
        #container { width: 100%; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id='container'>
    <canvas id='myChart'></canvas>
</div>
<script>
    Chart.defaults.global.animation.duration = 1000;
    Chart.defaults.global.animation.easing = 'linear';
    var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            labels: ['10','2000','30000','50000','60000','700000',],
            datasets: [
               {label: 'ABC' ,
                fill: true ,
                data: [ 
                  { x: '10', y: 2 },
                  { x: '2000', y: 4 },
                  { x: '30000', y: 7 },
                  { x: '50000', y: 8 },
                  { x: '60000', y: 8.5 },
                  { x: '700000', y: 9 }
                  ],
                borderWidth: 1},
             ]
        },
        options: {
            aspectRatio:  1.6,
            title: {
                display: true,
                position: 'top',
                text: 'Ref Data'
            },
            legend: {
                display: true,
                position: 'right',
            },
            scales: {
                yAxes: [{
                    id: 'first-y-Axis',
                    display: true,
                    scaleLabel: {
                       display: true,
                       labelString: 'Demo y-axis'
                    }
                    }],
                xAxes: [{
                    id: 'first-x-Axis',
                    display: true,
                    type: 'logarithmic',
                    scaleLabel: {
                       display: true,
                       labelString: 'Demo x-axis'
                    },
                    ticks: {
                       //min:  0 ,
                       //max:  700000
                       callback: function (value, index, values) {
                       if (Math.log10(value) % 1 === 0) { return value; }
                       }
                    }
                    }]
            },
            plugins: {
                colorschemes: {
                    scheme: 'brewer.Paired12'
                    }
                }
        }
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Similar solution is also discussed in the post **[linked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76618121/minor-grid-lines-in-log-chart-with-chartjs)** but the code used in that post is  very complex and I am unable to understand and make it work in my code as I don't know much about JavaScript. Just trying to make this graph for ine application. I'll thankful if someone here can modify my code or help me modify the code to get minor gridlines like the image or in the post linked above (except minor gridlines are created for y-axis in the post but I want for x-axis).

Best Regards

Comment: As stated at very beginning of the post you linked to, you don't have to do anything to have minor grid lines other than make sure your `ticks` `callback` returns `""` (an empty string),  for those ticks that don't have a label. The code in that post was about *styling* the minor lines and *filtering* the occasional unwanted grid line at such values as 15 or 150.

Comment: I also want to make to make minute gridlines thinner (and dashed) than the major one. I didn't lot of time we to copy paste the code from the linked post and tried to adjust it at various locations in my code but none worked. Can you help me in that too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As was the case in the OP [linked post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76618121/minor-grid-lines-in-log-chart-with-chartjs) (which was designed for the latest chart.js v4), it is still valid for chart.js v2+ that minor grid lines are created if `ticks.callback` returns an empty string instead of `null` or `undefined` (or if there's no `ticks.callback`).

However, there are differences in the way one may style the minor grid lines to differentiate them from major ones. In chart.js v2.9.4 scales' `gridLines` options are *not scriptable*. This calls for a different approach, one that might in some cases be useful for newer versions: using [indexable options](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/2.9.4/general/options.html#indexable-options),
which means that one has to create an array with a (different) value for each item - in this case for each grid line. Since the ticks are only known at runtime, one can create that array in an [axis callback](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/2.9.4/axes/#callbacks), e.g., in `afterBuildTicks`:

```js
afterBuildTicks(scale){
    const nTicks = scale.ticks.length,
        isMajor = scale.ticks.map(value => ('' + value).replace(/0+$/, '') === '1');
    scale.options.gridLines.lineWidth = 
        Array.from({length: nTicks}, (_, i) => isMajor[i] ? 1.2 : 0.5);
    scale.options.gridLines.color = 
        Array.from({length: nTicks}, (_, i) => isMajor[i] ? '#000' : '#ddd');
    //scale.options.gridLines.borderDash - can't be set as an array of arrays
}
```

Unfortunately, this approach doesn't seem to work for `borderDash`.

---

I'll give some details about what exactly how this function works: using an indexable option, let's say `gridLines.lineWidth`, means we set its value as an array:

```js
gridLines:{
    lineWidth: [1.2, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1.2, 0.5, .......]
}
```

The problem is that the ticks are built by chart.js from the data, we don't know beforehand how many ticks there are in total and how many and where are the major ones. So we have to wait for chart.js to build those ticks and then, in the handler automatically called immediately after the ticks are built, `afterBuildTicks`, we set the grid line properties, based on the actual tick values. This makes sense, since the gridlines are drawn after the ticks were built.

The function `afterBuildTicks` receives as an argument the scale object, from which we extract the ticks as `scale.ticks`. Then we decide which ticks will be "major" - to be drawn with a thicker line - the definition I used is that the string representation is a `1` fallowed by `0`s. An alternative, mathematical formulation can be devised, using `Math.log10`.

Now, we know how many ticks there are and where are the major ones so we can build the array introduced above for `gridLines.lineWidth`. The function `Array.from` is used; alternatively, we could have used `isMajor.map` with the same functions.

---

Code snippet:

```js
Chart.defaults.global.animation.duration = 1000;
Chart.defaults.global.animation.easing = 'linear';
const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: ['10', '2000', '30000', '50000', '60000', '700000',],
        datasets: [{
            label: 'ABC',
            fill: true,
            data: [{
                x: '10',
                y: 2
                },
                {
                    x: '2000',
                    y: 4
                },
                {
                    x: '30000',
                    y: 7
                },
                {
                    x: '50000',
                    y: 8
                },
                {
                    x: '60000',
                    y: 8.5
                },
                {
                    x: '700000',
                    y: 9
                }
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        },]
    },
    options: {
        aspectRatio: 1.6,
        title: {
            display: true,
            position: 'top',
            text: 'Ref Data'
        },
        legend: {
            display: true,
            position: 'right',
        },
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                id: 'first-y-Axis',
                display: true,
                scaleLabel: {
                    display: true,
                    labelString: 'Demo y-axis'
                }
            }],
            xAxes: [{
                id: 'first-x-Axis',
                display: true,
                type: 'logarithmic',
                scaleLabel: {
                    display: true,
                    labelString: 'Demo x-axis'
                },
                gridLines: {
                    borderDash: [10, 3],
                    drawTicks: false,
                    drawBorder: false
                },
                afterBuildTicks(scale){
                    const nTicks = scale.ticks.length,
                        isMajor = scale.ticks.map(value => ('' + value).charAt(0) === '1');
                    scale.options.gridLines.lineWidth = Array.from({length: nTicks}, (_, i) => isMajor[i] ? 1.2 : 0.5);
                    scale.options.gridLines.color = Array.from({length: nTicks}, (_, i) => isMajor[i] ? '#000' : '#ddd');
                    //scale.options.gridLines.borderDash - can't be set as an array of arrays
                },
                ticks: {
                    padding: 5,
                    autoSkip: false,
                    maxRotation: 0,
                    callback: function(value, index, values){
                        if(Math.log10(value) % 1 === 0){
                            return value;
                        }
                        return '';
                    }
                }
            }]
        },
        plugins: {
            colorschemes: {
                scheme: 'brewer.Paired12'
            }
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.bundle.min.js"
        integrity="sha512-SuxO9djzjML6b9w9/I07IWnLnQhgyYVSpHZx0JV97kGBfTIsUYlWflyuW4ypnvhBrslz1yJ3R+S14fdCWmSmSA=="
        crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-colorschemes"></script>        
<div style="min-height: 60vh">
    <canvas id="myChart">
    </canvas>
</div>
```

---

Per request, a version that should work in Internet Explorer and older browsers:

```js
afterBuildTicks: function(scale){
    var nTicks = scale.ticks.length,
        isMajor = scale.ticks.map(function(value){return ('' + value).replace(/0+$/, '') === '1';});
    scale.options.gridLines.lineWidth =
        isMajor.map(function(_, i){return isMajor[i] ? 1.2 : 0.5;})
    scale.options.gridLines.color =
        isMajor.map(function(_, i){return isMajor[i] ? '#000' : '#ddd';});
    //scale.options.gridLines.borderDash - can't be set as an array of arrays
}
```

and the full code in [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5gxybmhe/)

Comment: if want to do the same then xScale will be changed to yScale in the above code? Can you share some guide link on which I can understand how this code is functioning to make think/thin major/minor grids so that I can learn it?

Comment: Yes, it should work the same, just use the `afterBuildTicks` function for the other axis. I'll try to write another paragraph explaining what it's doing.

Comment: The code above was working fine in run code snippet but when I made html file of this code and run in internet explorer, it don't run and in the debugging, it says expected ':' line xx:colxx (ie. right after word `afterBuildTicks`. I need it for internet explorer because I am using this code to generate chart in Microsoft Access webBrowser control that actually IE11. Can you help me make this compatible with IE11. Sorry for sharing this info late because I didn't know that time that would make any difference.

Comment: I was using newer [syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions) for functions inside objects; to cover IE and  other browsers replace `afterBuildTicks(scale){` with `afterBuildTicks: function(scale){`. Also, `Array.from` and arrow functions might not work. I added a version for IE and older browsers, please let me know if it works, I don't have a windows machine to test it in IE.

Comment: Thanks for the updated code. Unfortunately it didn't work too on ie11. However when tried to make it compatible into ie11 using ChatGPT. It told me that the code is ES5 which (along with arrow functions) is not supported by ie11. ChatGPT converted the code to ES6 which I edited your answer and inserted the converted code and it is now working fine in ie11 too.

Comment: Have you used the code in the fiddle / from the section that I added for IE? Because that has no arrow function or `Array.from`; I saw that you edited the main section, which I'd prefer to remain as it is - if, we have to edit, we should do that to the IE version - and there only those lines that don't work.

Comment: I have tried now and it is working. It was my mistake, I left Math.log10 function that was not supported by IE too there which was causing issue. I used the code from jsfiddle and replace Math.log10 function with my custom function and now it is working fine. Thanks a lot.